# Spring Boot Gateway filter blocking requests

Tags: java, spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a Spring Gateway that needs to download a file before a request is fulfilled.
This is the filter that should achieve my goal:

```java
[...]
public class MyFilter implements GatewayFilter {
[...]
    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {
        return webClient.get().uri(uri).exchange().then(chain.filter(exchange));
    }
}
```

And it works, but this filter blocks the thread of the request until the file is downloaded, dramatically limiting the number of concurrent requests.

How can I achieve a better parallelism?

Comment: Check this out -> https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#then-reactor.core.publisher.Mono-. `.then` function wait till first `Mono` (`webClient.get().uri(uri).exchange()`) reference to be completed. That's why until the download completed, `request` holds. Try changing the order of execution like, `chain.filter(exchange).then(webClient.get().uri(uri).exchange())`.

Comment: @sachith-dickwella I tried that, but the result is the same.

Comment: I *think* filters will always have to complete before the request by their nature, so this is likely the issue rather than the publisher chain. Not confident enough to give that as an answer though, I could be wrong.